# Duplicate rows in R N times and adding new count column

Tags: r, loops, row, paste

Ciao: Here is the data I have "have"

```
  have = data.frame(c(1,2,3),
                      c(90,87,71),
                      c(600,601,602))
    colnames(have) <- c("STUDENT","SCORE","TYPE")
```

Here is the data I want "want"

```
  want = data.frame(c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                      c(90,90,87,87,71,71),
                      c(600,600,601,601,602,602),
                      c(100,101,100,101,100,101))

    colnames(want) <- c("STUDENT","SCORE","TYPE","CLASS")
```

As shown above here starting from "have" data I want to copy the row for every STUDENT; add new column "CLASS" which is equals to 100 for the STUDENT's first row and 101 for the STUDENT's second row.

Cheers!

Comment: Besides the data you 'have' and the one you 'want', can we also see your attempt please?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows('100' = have, '101' = have, .id = 'CLASS')`

Comment: @李哲源 What is instead of 100:101 there is 90,99--i try CLASS=90,99 but get error~ arguments imply differing number of rows

Comment: An imo better alternative: `have %>% full_join(., crossing(STUDENT = have$STUDENT, CLASS = 100:101))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating a additional key for `merge`

```
have$key=1
mergedf=data.frame('CLASS'=c(100,101),'key'=1)
merge(have,mergedf,all.x=T)
  key STUDENT SCORE TYPE CLASS
1   1       1    90  600   100
2   1       1    90  600   101
3   1       2    87  601   100
4   1       2    87  601   101
5   1       3    71  602   100
6   1       3    71  602   101
```

Answer (score 1):

李哲源 plus Axeman provided the answers

```
## R core
data.frame(have[rep(1:nrow(have), each = 2), ], CLASS = c(100, 101),
           row.names = seq_len(2 * nrow(have))) 

## dplyr
dplyr::bind_rows('100' = have, '101' = have, .id = 'CLASS')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
classes <- as.matrix(seq(100,101, by=1))
classes_rep <-matrix(classes, nrow=nrow(have)*nrow(classes))
want <- cbind(rbind(have, have), classes_rep)
```